# Javascript pdfKit "Error: write after end" due to closed stream...?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdfkit

I am closing my writing connection in a "finally" block but even after going into this block the program seems to go back into the try block. 
Here is the code :

```
    function printAllAssetsAndThreats(startX, startY) {
      try {

    con.query("SELECT * FROM Kunde1Assets;", function (err, result, fields) {
      for (var i in result) {
        console.log("b");
        myDoc.font('Helvetica-Bold')
        .fontSize(20)
        .text('str', startX, startY);

        var xxx = result[i].KundenAssetID;

        startY = startY + 50;
        //jetzt jeweils alle gefährdungen:
        var sql = "SELECT DISTINCT c.AID, b.GID, b.Name, c.Name AS Asset  FROM Kunde1Verbindungen a, Gefährdungen b, Kunde1Assets c  WHERE a.KundenAssetID =  \"" + xxx + " \"AND a.GID = b.GID  AND c.KundenAssetID = a.KundenAssetID";
        con.query(sql, function (err, result2, fields) {
          for (var i2 in result2) {

          }
        });
        ///////////////////



      }
    });
  } catch (e) {
  } finally {
    console.log("a");
    end();
  }
}
```

So even after printing "a" there´ll be "b" printed in the console. 
Thank you for your help !!!

Tim

EDIT

I have tried rewriting the code f.e. with callbacks but it´s still not working as it is supposed to do

```
start(()=>{

  myDoc.end();
});

 function start(callback){
  console.log("hello");
  myDoc.font('Helvetica-Bold')
  .fontSize(20)
  .text('str', 44,44);
    con.query("SELECT * FROM Kunde1Assets;", function (err, result, fields) {
      console.log("hello");
      var counter=0;
   for(var i in result){
     console.log("hello");
     start2(result[i].KundenAssetID, ()=>{});
     counter++;
      if (counter==result.length){
     console.log("yo");break;callback();
   }
   if (counter==result.length){
    console.log("yo");callback();
  }

   }
//


      });

}
 function start2(kaid, callback){
        var sql = "SELECT DISTINCT c.AID, b.GID, b.Name, c.Name AS Asset  FROM Kunde1Verbindungen a, Gefährdungen b, Kunde1Assets c  WHERE a.KundenAssetID =  \"" + kaid + " \"AND a.GID = b.GID  AND c.KundenAssetID = a.KundenAssetID";
        con.query(sql, function (err, result2, fields) {
          for (var i2 in result2) {
            console.log(kaid +"---"+ result2[i2].Name);
            myDoc.font('Helvetica-Bold')
            .fontSize(20)
            .text('str', 44,44);
          }
        });

}
```

EDIT:
Tried it with promises (not working yet)

```
myDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('node.pdf'));

var promise = start();
promise.then(function(result){

  console.log(result);
  myDoc.end();
})  
   function start(){
     return new Promise (function(resolve, reject){
      con.query("SELECT * FROM Kunde1Assets;", function (err, result, fields) {
        console.log(result);
        for (var i in result){
           myDoc.font('Helvetica-Bold')
          .fontSize(20)
          .text(result[i].Name, 30, 20+(i*30));

          var promise2 = start2 (result[i].KundenAssetID);
          promise.then(function(name){
            for (var i2 in name){
              myDoc.font('Helvetica-Bold')
              .fontSize(20)
              .text('result[i].Name', 30, 20+(i2*30));
            }
          });
        }

        resolve(result);
        if (Error) reject();
        });
     }); 
  }


   function start2(kaid){
     return new Promise(function( resolve, reject){
       var sql = "SELECT DISTINCT c.AID, b.GID, b.Name, c.Name AS Asset  FROM Kunde1Verbindungen a, Gefährdungen b, Kunde1Assets c  WHERE a.KundenAssetID =  \"" + kaid + " \"AND a.GID = b.GID  AND c.KundenAssetID = a.KundenAssetID";
          con.query(sql, function (err, result2, fields) {
            for (var i2 in result2) {
              //console.log(kaid +"---"+ result2[i2].Name);


            }
           resolve(result2);
           if (Error) reject();
          });
     });       
  }
```

Comment: Is `con.query` asynchronous?

Comment: You're passing an anonymous callback to `con.query`, which is executed at some indefinite time *after* `printAllAssetsAndThreats` has finished. You are running your 2nd query at the correct place, keep using this pattern and move everything you want to happen after the 2nd query inside its callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `try/catch/finally` block is running synchronously. It will hit the `finally` within the first tick of the JS event loop. However (I assume, based on the structure of the callback), the `con.query()` function is asynchronous. That means that it will run in *at least* the tick after your finally. Therefore, this will always run after everything inside the finally.

If you want it to work as expected, look into asynchronous methods of achieving the `try/catch/finally` structure. There are million ways to skin a cat in regards to this, the async library, promises, etc. Or just keep any code you want to run after the connection inside the connection callback.

Either way, the issue is a combination of sync and async code running alongside each other.

Comment: Hey Matt
thank you for your help.
If i understood correct i can solve this problem by putting each con.query() in a method which is for example executed synchronous isn´t it ?
I am still struggling with geeting this done